# v4lvj drawing lines on top of webcam image

Tags: java, webcam, v4l

I am following a tutorial on the v4lvj library that allows access to webcams on a linux. [link to source](http://code.google.com/p/v4l4j/wiki/Examples) I wrote the example program that basically displays the video feed of your webcamera. Everything works just as the program described. The problem comes in when I try to alter the program by adding a green line ontop of the video feed. I simply grab the graphics the same way, set the line color and then draw the line.

```
@Override
        public void nextFrame(VideoFrame frame) {
                // This method is called when a new frame is ready.
                // Don't forget to recycle it when done dealing with the frame.

                // draw the new frame onto the JLabel
                label.getGraphics().drawImage(frame.getBufferedImage(), 0, 0, width, height, null);
                label.getGraphics().setColor(Color.GREEN); //this line causes exceptions
                label.getGraphics().drawLine(0, 0, 640, 480); //this line causes exceptions 

                // recycle the frame
                frame.recycle();
        }
```

When I do that though, I get some exceptions preceded by "It seems your JVM is unable to decode this image. Supported image types: BMP bmp jpg JPG..." and then

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported marker type 0x5a
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImage(Native Method)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1176)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:984)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1438)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1342)
    at au.edu.jcu.v4l4j.JPEGVideoFrame.refreshBufferedImage(Unknown Source)
    at au.edu.jcu.v4l4j.BaseVideoFrame.getBufferedImage(Unknown Source)
    at SimpleViewer.nextFrame(SimpleViewer.java:143)
    at au.edu.jcu.v4l4j.PushSource.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
au.edu.jcu.v4l4j.exceptions.V4L4JException: Exception received while grabbing next frame
    at au.edu.jcu.v4l4j.PushSource.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: au.edu.jcu.v4l4j.exceptions.UnsupportedMethod: Unable to decode the image
    at au.edu.jcu.v4l4j.JPEGVideoFrame.refreshBufferedImage(Unknown Source)
    at au.edu.jcu.v4l4j.BaseVideoFrame.getBufferedImage(Unknown Source)
    at SimpleViewer.nextFrame(SimpleViewer.java:143)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported marker type 0x5a
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImage(Native Method)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1176)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:984)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1438)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1342)
    ... 5 more
```

Could anyone tell me why and help me draw a line ontop of a video feed. Thank you.

Comment: On top of that, even if I remove those two lines, the program will continue to terminate the same way until I unplug and then replug in the web camera

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: I haven't, but I haven't looked at it in awhile...

Answer (score 0):

You should do your painting by overriding `paint(Graphics g)` method of `JLabel`,
then do a cast `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;` and use `Graphics2D` for painting.

It is incorrect way you use JLabel in your code.

You could use also `BufferedImage` you received from frame, get their `Graphics` and draw on it